# Custom Inspector for textures?

Tags: unity, textures, image, editors

I am working with an open source project called [Project Porcupine](https://github.com/TeamPorcupine/ProjectPorcupine). The project is a game engine for a base building game that allows for one to extend the game. We have a system to [read texture files, and use a .XML configuration file](https://github.com/TeamPorcupine/ProjectPorcupine/tree/master/Assets/StreamingAssets/Images) to parse the details of that file. This to me seems like a good use case for a custom inspector. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to even configure the script to read in images as such, and google is letting me down. How can I write a custom editor for an image, even better if limited to a folder? Thanks!

EDIT

To clear things up a bit, I'm trying to make a custom inspector for images in the /StreamingAssets folder. These assets are included with the build, and thus editable in Unity, but I would like to make a tool to make editing these a bit easier. Right now the inspector looks like this, the problem I'm having is getting anything to appear on the inspector at all.

[image]

I've tried two things, first a Custom Inspector on TextureImporter, and using the following code, neither of which seemed to do anything. I would be happy to get anything printed in the Inspector, from that point I can figure out the rest, I hope. Thanks!

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpriteXmlViewer : AssetPostprocessor
{
    void OnPreprocessTexture()
    {
        GUILayout.Label("Hello OnInspectorGUI!");
        Debug.Log("Test");
    }
}
```

Lastly, I'm clicking on the following image for the display above:

[image]

Comment: It's not clear to me which step in the process you need help with. Is it in reading the image file from a folder path or URL using [WWW.texture](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW-texture.html)? Or setting up the inspector UI to assign & preview the texture? Or some other detail?  Try editing your question to show us what you have so far, what your end goal is (eg. a mock-up image), and where you're stuck.

Comment: Setting up the inspector UI for setting up the texture. I'll add in a bit to help.